# How do I kill the Pope?

Tags: europa-universalis-iv

I've been playing for 60 in-game years. However, the pope has yet to change even once. Right now I have 72.7% chance of becoming curia controller. In CK2 an "unfortunate and tragic accident" of falling down the cliff would do. In EU4 how do I kill the pope or any ruler in general?

Note: mine is Roman Empire and my capital is in Roma. Papal State doesn't show up in the map. 99% of my region is Catholic. The game is a converted CK2 game.

Edit: The Pope finally kicked the bucket. Now I am finally the Curia Controller. However, it took 3 succession in 70ish years before he finally died. The question still stands. Is there any way to quicken the unfortunate death?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The curia doesn't work, if the Papal State doesn't exist. Normally, when the Papal State is destroyed, which it is due to your converted CK2 save, another catholic theocracy becomes the Papal State. If none of those exist as well, the Papal State is gone forever and the curia is removed.

I presume, due to your save game conversion the trigger to remove the curia didn't fire or the trigger to move the papal state to another theocracy, if it exists, didn't fire. So whoever is curia controller now will remain so for all eternity. You may possibly destroy the curia, when you conquer whoever is curia controller now, but I'm not sure.

Edit regarding your edit:

Seems, the game somehow fixed itself. Possibly a catholic theocracy emerged somewhere and created the papacy or it's just something that happens with the converted. In any case 70 years is unnatural, the pope is usually very old, when he takes office already and a papacy rarely lasts for more than 20 years.

Regarding your question in accelerating the process, no. EU4 doesn't have the character level mechanics CK2 has. There is absolutely no way to influence another nations ruler or the popes demise except beating them in combat, when they choose to lead armies personally.